# Rails devise authentication, exclude login screen layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a devise authentication. I want the login page to come on a blank page. So, render ' layouts/navigation '.... <% = Render ' layouts/Topnavbar '%>..... <% = Render ' layouts/footer '% > I don't want this to be seen. How can I do that?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  ##    milia defines a default max_tenants, invalid_tenant exception 
   handling
  ##    but you can override these if you wish to handle directly
  rescue_from ::Milia::Control::MaxTenantExceeded, :with => :max_tenants
  rescue_from ::Milia::Control::InvalidTenantAccess, :with => :invalid_tenant


  before_action :authenticate_tenant!
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<div id="wrapper">    
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>

  <!-- Page wraper -->
  <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

      <!-- Page wrapper -->
      <%= render 'layouts/topnavbar' %>

      <!-- Main view  -->
      <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      <%= yield %>

      <!-- Footer -->
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

  </div>
  <!-- End page wrapper-->
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def index                   
    @users = User.all
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted"
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
        redirect_to user_path, :success => 'User updated'
    else
        redirect_to user_path :alert => 'Unable to update user'
    end
end

end
```

I understand... Unfortunately it does not work... I assume the Milia gem file does not use control. I used Milia/sessions not devise/sessions in routes. Uses the Milia members and users controls. Where render layout: false did not work

```
resources :members
  get 'home/index'

  root :to => "home#index"


  # *MUST* come *BEFORE* devise's definitions (below)
  as :user do   
    match '/user/confirmation' => 'milia/confirmations#update', :via => :put, :as => :update_user_confirmation
  end


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
    :registrations => "milia/registrations",
    :confirmations => "milia/confirmations",
    :sessions => "milia/sessions", 
    :passwords => "milia/passwords", 
  }
```

Comment: I've posted an answer to fully disable layout. Do you want to fully disable layout for this page or just hide all layout partials?

Comment: Is this work for you or no? `<%= render 'layouts/navigation' if controller_name != 'milia/sessions' || action_name != 'new' %>` I've fixed again the controller name. If it's not... then place debugger in layout and check what controller_name/action_name do you have on signin page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fully disable layout for login**

Generate devise controllers in console

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

Call `render layout: false` in the end of `new` action

**Disable specific partials inside layout, but leave basic layout**

`<%= render 'layouts/navigation' if controller_name != 'milia/sessions' || action_name != 'new' %>`

Better to put this condition into helper

Comment: I am in co-working place. It will require me to move in another place to have a call. What do you mean about 'I created a deverse controller, but still no navbar etc'?

Comment: Do you mean that navbar is always hidden now? (after you add my condition)

Comment: Can you provide outputs for: 1. Console command `rake routes | grep sessions`; 2. Your `sessions_controller`;

Comment: Renamed controller in my answer

Comment: Missed `create` with `new`

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me. You think it's a neat code? Thanks for the help.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>

      <!-- Page wraper -->
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

          <!-- Page wrapper -->
          <%= render 'layouts/topnavbar' %>

          <!-- Main view  -->          
          <%= yield %>

          <!-- Footer -->
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

      </div>     
      <!-- End page wrapper--> 
    <% end %>
    <div class="gray-bg">
      <%= yield if controller_name != 'milia/sessions' && action_name == 'new' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```